# Android CookieManager fails to refresh cookies

Tags: android

Curently in my Android app, I am using `CookieManager` and `CookieSyncManager`.
What I notice is that, the cookie is not updated properly.

For example:

```
Android ----> Server: No cookie
Server  ----> Android: Cookie C1
Android ----> Server: Cookie C1 (Correct)
Server  ----> Android: Cookie C2
Android ----> Server: Cookie C1 C2 (Incorrect)
```

Because of the 2 cookies returned, server side rejected the transaction.

I have tried to force sync, but the issue still persists.
I even tried to add some sleep, but it did not help either.

Any suggestion on what else I can try?

Thank a lot.

Regards
Andrew

```
cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cookieInput = cookieManager.getCookie(Constants.HOST_URL);

write("Cookie from CookieManager 4:" + cookieInput);


cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

//SystemClock.sleep(2000);

cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cookieInput = cookieManager.getCookie(Constants.HOST_URL);

write("Cookie from CookieManager 5:" + cookieInput);


cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();

cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

//SystemClock.sleep(2000);

//CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();


cookieManager.setCookie(Constants.HOST_URL, cookieString);

cookieManager.setCookie(Constants.HOST_URL, cookieString1);

cookieManager.setCookie(Constants.HOST_URL, cookieString2);

//SystemClock.sleep(5000);

cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cookieInput = cookieManager.getCookie(Constants.HOST_URL);

write("Cookie from CookieManager 6:" + cookieInput); 


CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

//SystemClock.sleep(30000);
```